# How to configure java setting for my new project?

Tags: java, shell

I have started learning algorithm in java, but there are lot of things getting in my way unlike python or ruby. I wanted to well structure my source code for future references, here is my directory structure.

```
~/workspace/algorithms/
      |---searching/BinarySearch.java
      |---sorting/InsertionSort.java
```

The `InsertionSort.java` file consists of this package:

```
package algorithms.sorting;

class InsertionSort {...}
```

I am able to compile my java source but I am having trouble running the program. I may also need to import code from any package inside `algorithms` to any package.

How to compile and run programs keeping my package structure intact from vim or command line? what should be my current directory while running commands?

PS: I am a `vim` user and don't want to abandon it just for the sake of Java.

Comment: Looks like a classpath issue.

Comment: Take a look at ant, maven, gradle or sbt. And seriously consider using an IDE for Java, I've been using vim for 20+ years but I generally prefer an IDE for programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath should point to `~/workspace`. Then on the command line enter:

```
> java algorithms.sorting.InsertionSort
```

This will call the `main()` method of your `InsertionSort` class.